# Why does Sizeof operator on a std::string yield unexpected result?

Tags: c++, string, sizeof

In the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char buff[100];
    _snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "%s %d", "Name",2); //snprintf incase of ideone
    string buffAsStdStr = buff;
    cout<<buffAsStdStr<<endl;
    cout<<"len: "<<buffAsStdStr.length()<<endl;
    cout<<sizeof(buffAsStdStr)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The length of the string in buffAsStdStr is 6 but the value the sizeof show is 28 when I run in Visual Studio 2012 and 32 in ideone.
The expected size is 7 right including the trailing NULL char.

What is the reason for this unexpected result of sizeof operator?
Why does the result change across visual studio and ideone?

Comment: The reason is that your expectations were wrong :)

Comment: The question does make sense, especially for someone who is starting learning C++.

Comment: @Mr.C64 yes I am a beginner. Now understood and crystal clear. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`sizeof` of a `std::string` instance just returns the size, in bytes, of the "internal representation" of the `std::string`, i.e. you can think of it like the sum of the `sizeof`s of each `std::string`'s data members (there may be padding involved as well).

For example, in 32-bit debug builds with VS2015, `sizeof(std::string)` returns 28; in 64-bit debug builds I get 40; in 32-bit release builds I get 24, and in 64-bit release builds 32.

That's because the *internal* representation of `std::string` *changes* with different build options: e.g. debug builds usually contain additional mechanics to help spotting bugs, which grows the size of the representation; moreover, in 64-bit builds the pointers are larger, so again the size increases with respect to 32-bit builds, etc.

So, the number you get from `sizeof` invoked on a `std::string` instance is in general *different* from the number of `char`s that make the string's text. To get this number, you have to call [`std::string::size` or `std::string::length`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size).

Comment: Interesting.  The small string buffer is clearly 16 bytes in Visual Studio.  I'm slightly surprised they didn't make it 20 in a 32-bit build so the size was a multiple of 8.  Perhaps they no longer care about 32-bit builds.

Comment: @MartinBonner: In VS2015, `sizeof(std::string)` is **24** (3x8) in 32-bit _release_ builds :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`std::string::size`, or `std::string::length`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size).

`sizeof` returns size of object, it's not count of chars contained.

Comment: std::string::size and std::string::length both returns the same. As 6.

Comment: Yes. It doesn't count null terminator.

Comment: @ShameelMohamed  You don't get it really, do you?

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that `sizeof(buffAsStdStr)` is not the length of the string but the size of the `std::string` instance, and every instance of a given type has the same size.

The result of `sizeof` is determined during compilation, and if you have an object `o` of type `T`, `sizeof(o)` and `sizeof(T)` are equivalent.

Also, an `std::string` is not required to store a trailing null character, and may contain "non-terminating" null characters.